# Why is the available space not increased when i increase the quota of the ZFS share?

Tags: zfs, truenas, quota, zpool

I'm not very familiar with ZFS and need to increase the size of an ZFS share on our FreeNAS.
When i do `zpool list` i see that we have 2 ZFS pools:

```
NAME           SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
Volume1       1.98T  1.00T  1003G         -    26%    50%  1.00x  ONLINE  /mnt
Volume2       1.98T   140G  1.85T         -     2%     6%  1.00x  ONLINE  /mnt
```

The share i want to increase in size is a directory on `Volume1` named `releases` (should go from 100G to 150G)

```
[root@axxfile] ~# zfs list | grep releases
Volume1/releases                                           100G   280K   100G  /mnt/Volume1/releases

[root@axxfile] ~# zfs get quota Volume1/releases
NAME              PROPERTY  VALUE  SOURCE
Volume1/releases  quota     100G   local
```

To increase the size i did: `zfs set quota=150 Volume1/releases` which resulted in:

```
[root@axxfile] ~# zfs list | grep releases
Volume1/releases                                           100G   280K   100G  /mnt/Volume1/releases

[root@axxfile] ~# zfs get quota Volume1/releases
NAME              PROPERTY  VALUE  SOURCE
Volume1/releases  quota     150G   local
```

For some reason the quota is increased from 100G to 150G but the "available space" is still 100G. After asking Google for a solution i found that i increased the ZFS share but the OS does not know this so i need to tell it to the OS with something like

```
[root@axxfile] ~# growfs -M /mnt/Volume1/releases/ Volume1/releases
growfs: illegal option -- M
usage: growfs [-Ny] [-s size] special | filesystem
```

As you can see, this does not work because of `-M` is not a valid property. I tried continue Googling but was not able to come to a solution. Maybe someone can help me out by explaining what i'm doing wrong or which step i missed?

Maybe its good to know is that we use an old version (9.3) of FreeNAS. An update is planned for nearby future but we where not able to do it yet.

**============== UPDATE 1 ============**
@Michael Hampton

I notice that refquota is still 100G, that is the problem i guess?

```
[root@axxfile] ~# zfs get quota,reservation,refquota,refreservation Volume1/releases
NAME              PROPERTY        VALUE      SOURCE
Volume1/releases  quota           150G       local
Volume1/releases  reservation     none       local
Volume1/releases  refquota        100G       local
Volume1/releases  refreservation  none       local

[root@axxfile] ~# zfs get -r reservation,refreservation -t filesystem,volume Volume1
cannot open '-t': dataset does not exist
cannot open 'filesystem,volume': invalid dataset name
NAME                                              PROPERTY        VALUE      SOURCE
Volume1                                           reservation     none       local
Volume1                                           refreservation  none       local
Volume1/VM                                        reservation     none       local
Volume1/VM                                        refreservation  none       local
Volume1/ab                                        reservation     none       local
Volume1/ab                                        refreservation  none       local
Volume1/backup                                    reservation     none       default
Volume1/backup                                    refreservation  none       default
Volume1/backup/cloneimages                        reservation     none       local
Volume1/backup/cloneimages                        refreservation  none       local
Volume1/backup/sicherungen                        reservation     none       local
Volume1/backup/sicherungen                        refreservation  none       local
Volume1/backup/switch                             reservation     none       default
Volume1/backup/switch                             refreservation  none       default
Volume1/jails                                     reservation     none       default
Volume1/jails                                     refreservation  none       default
Volume1/mailserver                                reservation     none       local
Volume1/mailserver                                refreservation  none       local
Volume1/releases                                  reservation     none       local
Volume1/releases                                  refreservation  none       local
```

Comment: Please post the output of `zfs get quota,reservation,refquota,refreservation Volume1/releases`  and the output of `zfs get -r reservation,refreservation -t filesystem,volume Volume1` .

Comment: @MichaelHampton, `zfs get quota,reservation,refquota,refreservation Volume1/releases` did the trick. Whats the difference between quota and refquota? (same for reservation). Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the reply of `@Michael Hampton` i noticed that also a `refquota` was set for the share (data set). After i changed the `refquota` with `zfs set refquota=150G Volume1/releases` the problem was solved.

This explains pretty well what the difference is between `quota` and `refquota`:

*Quota limits the overall size of a dataset and all of it's children and snapshots while refquota applies to only to data directly referred to from within that dataset.*

*Quota would be useful if you delegated a dataset to another user (with permission to create additional datasets under that one) or if you wanted to limit the overall size of a given dataset. For instance, the /home directory of a multi user file server could be limited to 10TB, which would ensure that the sum of all user home datasets and snapshots of said datasets could not exceed 10TB.*

*Refquota would be helpful if you had users who tend to overload a specific dataset. In our above example, each users home directory might be limited to a 100GB quota and a 50GB refquota. This would mean their home directory could contain 50GB of data, but the sum of the live dataset and all snapshots couldn't exceed 100GB.*

Source: [the difference between quota and refquota](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/6ita0l/can_someone_explain_the_difference_between_quota/)